# Is there a way to Add to a List two variables with one line of code?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int[,] map = new int[,]
{
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
};

int[,] map1 = new int[,]
{
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
 {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
};

        private List<Texture2D> tileTextures = new List<Texture2D>();
        private List<int[,]> MapsArrays = new List<int[,]>();

        public void AddMaps()
        {
            MapsArrays.Add(map);
            MapsArrays.Add(map1);
        }
```

Now i'm doing Add(map) then Add(map1)...But if i will have sometimes 30 maps variables.
How can i add them all automatic maybe with a loop to get all the variables start with map and add them ?

Comment: Why not put them in a collection (Array/List) to begin with?  This looks remarkably like data and not code, so I also question why this data isn't being loaded from an external file entirely.

Comment: have you tried merging those maps to one array? maybe a 3d array? then adding them through a for loop? though there are good answers here you can try

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `AddRange` extension method:

```
MapsArrays.AddRange(new [] { map, map1 });
```

Bear in mind that you may need your `MapsArrays` to be cast as `List<Map>` for that to work.

(Don't be afraid to try Simon's solution as well, it's not bad at all)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way I'll throw in there.

Without knowing your exact structure I would just say "add them inline". That is, don't declare them separately and just add them straight into your list. Another option is a dictionary for the lookup:

```
private IDictionary<string, int[,]> maps = new Dictionary<string, int[,]>();

public void Init() {
    maps.Add("map", new int[,]
        {
         {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
         {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
         {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,},
         {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
         {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,},
         {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,},
         {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
         {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
        });

    maps.Add("map1", new int[,] ... // second one here
}
```

This has the benefit of fast lookups if you need to reference them.. but also allows you to just declare the maps once (where they are added to the dictionary). Then you can reference them via their key:

```
var map1 = maps["map1"];
```

Comment: The question clearly states "one line of code" ... for some reason.

Comment: While you're right - this will allow the OP to declare once and the dictionary will just grow. So.. the code will become smaller. I just thought I would put it out there anyway.

Comment: yeah I find it a better solution, honestly, but I got the sense that we're supposed to stick to the requirements of the question.  And no, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave it there anyway given that it could potentially be a solution for others asking similar questions. That is worth the `-2` rep :)

Answer (score 0):

To do that in one line, you can make your own Extension method :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddMany<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] input)
    {
        list.AddRange(input);
    }
}
```

which you can use like that :

```
public void AddMaps()
{
    MapsArrays.AddMany(map, map1, map2);
}
```